# SQL Server/SSMS, Select > Case statement error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2000.000000' to data type int."

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, int

I have a table with multiple records (20million+)

I have one column, the data type is currently varchar and I'm trying to use a select > case statement, however I keep receiving the following error:

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2000.000000' to
>   data type int."

What I don't understand is why this is seen as a varchar value when its a number. Every time I try to run the code it failes on a different line, same issue, different number

This is my code - can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please? thanks

```
   Select 
  Amount_range,
  Sum(isnull(cast(Amount as float),0)) as TotalAmt, 
  count(*) as Count

 FROM (Select Amount, 
                Sum(isnull(cast(Amount as float),0)) as TotalAmt, 
                count(*) as Count,
                  case 
                 when Amount between 0 and 50000.000000 then '0=50'
                 when Amount between 50000.100000 and 100000.000000 then '50=100'
                 when Amount > 100000.000000  then '100+'
                 end as Amount_range
                 from [dbo].[TableName001] group by Amount) a

 where Amount is not null   
 Group by   Amount_range 
 Having count(*) > 0;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the datatype of column amount

Comment: @JayShankarGupta its varchar. i used bulk insert to get the data into sql server

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest not using `float`, it's not as accurate as `decimal` and `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to cast `amount` in `case` also**

```
Select Amount_range,
       Sum(isnull(cast(Amount as float),0)) as TotalAmt, 
       count(*) as Count
FROM (Select Amount, 
             Sum(isnull(cast(Amount as float),0)) as TotalAmt, 
             count(*) as Count,
             case 
                 when cast(Amount as float) between 0 and 50000.000000 then '0=50'
                 when cast(Amount as float) between 50000.100000 and 100000.000000 then '50=100'
                 when cast(Amount as float) > 100000.000000  then '100+'
             end as Amount_range
             from [dbo].[TableName001] group by Amount) a
 where Amount is not null   
 Group by Amount_range 
 Having count(*) > 0;
```

Comment: Welcome :-) @SS360

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert amount column to float as between  operator works only for numeric columns not for varchar columns